# Bind Control to SubClass

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding

I have a checkbox that I want to bind to a subclass.  The DataSource uses the ParentClass as the business object. Is it possible? Something like:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb" Text="Test" Checked='<%# Bind("ChildClass.Test") %>' />

public class ParentClass {
   private ChildClass _ChildClass;

   public ChildClass ChildClass {
     get { return _ChildClass; }
     set { _ChildClass = value; }
   }

}

public ChildClass ChildClass {
   private bool _Test;

   public bool Test {
      get { return _Test; }
      Set { _Test = value; }
   }    
}
```

Comment: You went to the trouble of typing it out here. Surely attempting it to determine if it's possible wouldn't be much harder than hitting debug on a test page.

Comment: Sorry I should have said I get an error could not find property named ChildClass.Test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Eval for one-way binding.  Two-way binding with Bind is not possible for subclass properties.